# How do i transition between game and menu without using frames in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, menu, navigation, onclicklistener

I have simplified this code for easier reading

I have one class called LevelSelect, 
       one class called Game,
   and one class called NavButtons.
*/

```
The code below i have added levelSelect MovieClip to the stage and 
added level numbers to level boxes
onclick it goes to my selected level.

public class LevelSelectPage extends Game
{
    public var levelSelectScreen:level_selection;
    public var list:Array;
    // add movieClips to L1,L2 etc...
    public static var Level:String = "No Level Selected";
    public static var shared:SharedObject;


    public function LevelSelectPage( ) 
    {
        setUpLevelSelect(); 
    }

    public function setUpLevelSelect():void
    {
        shared = SharedObject.getLocal("savegame");
        shared.clear(); // remove when game completed
        if (shared.data.level_passed == undefined)
        {
            shared.data.level_passed = 3;
        }
        if (shared.data.playing_level == undefined)
        {
            shared.data.playing_level = "L0";
        } 
        else
        {
            shared.data.playing_level = "L0";
        }

        levelSelectScreen = new level_selection();

        addChild(levelSelectScreen);

        AddMovieClipsForLevels(); 
    }

    public function AddMovieClipsForLevels():void 
    {
        // array of movieClip instances... level pictures.
        list  = [
                        levelSelectScreen.L1,
                        levelSelectScreen.L2,
                        levelSelectScreen.L3
                ];

        list.forEach(setupSquare);  

    }

    public function setupSquare(square:MovieClip, index:int, array:Array):void
    {
        // add numbers on top of level images

        // get numbers of the levels... as index starts from 0, add 1
        var LevelNumber:Number = index + 1;

        // convert number to string
        var imageLevelNumber:String = LevelNumber.toString();
// set textfield     // get childs instance name    
             var     insertlevelNumber:TextField 
            =  square.getChildByName("levelNumberText") as TextField;
        // output text
        insertlevelNumber.text = imageLevelNumber;

    }

    public function onSquareClick(me:MouseEvent):void
    {

        switch(me.currentTarget.name)
        {
            case "L1":   // trace("level 1 was selected");
            // startGame();
            break;  

        }

    }

}
}

public class Game
{
    // imagen a blank screen, it doesn't matter
}
```

The code bellow - i have added the nav buttons to the game stage, and on click of the back button it outputs a trace statment
but how do i run the LevelSelectPage again instead ?

```
public class NavButtons
{
    private var m_NavDisplayIcon:ReferenceArray;
    private var m_stage:Stage;


    public function NavButtons( stage:Stage )
    { 
        // add navigation to stage
        m_stage = stage;

        m_NavDisplayIcon = new ReferenceArray( navDisplayFla );

        var icon:navDisplayFla = new navDisplayFla( );

            icon.x = 5;
            icon.y = 5;

            m_NavDisplayIcon.Add( icon );

            m_stage.addChild( icon );

        // addEventlisteners for backButton, pause game and information

        icon.backIcon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,    goBackToLevelSelectPage);
        icon.pauseIcon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pauseGame);
        icon.informationIcon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,     showInformation);
    }

    public function goBackToLevelSelectPage( event:MouseEvent ):void
    {

        //var levelSelectScreen:level_selection = new LevelSelectPage();
        //m_stage.addChild(levelSelectScreen);
        trace("you pressed the backButton");

    }
```

Comment: By uncommenting the code supposed to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Think of the stage as a blank piece of paper onto which you can stick post-it notes. So when you begin the game, your piece of paper is blank, and you add a post-it note onto this blank "stage" that contains your level selectscreen.

You do this by adding movieclips or sprites to the stage, or better yet add one container to the stage to which you will then add all additional elements (this will make it easier later because you can remove the container and everything in it will be removed as well in one go).

Now, when the player clicks on a button on your level select screen, what you need to do is:

1. Remove the current post-it note that's on the paper (i.e, remove the container that has your level select screen).
2. Place a new post-it note that contains the level the player clicked on (i.e, now you add another container to the stage, and add all the elements of the new level into it.)

When the user wants to go back to the level select screen, all you do is again remove the post-it note that is on the paper currently, and add the post-it note that contains the level select screen.

Comment: The code on the levelselect.as is not shown on the levelselectscreen movieclip. When my game starts the levelselectscreen.as loads which add the levelselect container and also the code to add numbers on to the levels, if i just load the movieclip there is no numbers etc. When i click on the level it goes to the game. The game level has the navigation buttons on it, but when i click on the back button i need to run the levelselect class again. As the levelselect class adds the containers for my levels already. But i dont know how run my levelselect class on click. thank u for your fast response

Comment: The code on the levelselect.as is not shown on the levelselectscreen movieclip. When my game starts the levelselectscreen.as loads which add the levelselect container and also the code to add numbers on to the levels, if i just load the movieclip there is no numbers etc. When i click on the level it goes to the game. The game level has the navigation buttons on it, but when i click on the back button i need to run the levelselect class again. As the levelselect class also adds the numbers etc for my levels. But i dont know how run my levelselect class on click. thank u for your fast response

Comment: im using flash develop with flash aswell :(